# Scatter plot using sympy

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

Is it possible to scatter plot using sympy? I have 2 arrays; call them A and B. I can do a scatter plot using matplotlib like this:

```
plt.plot(A,B)
```

I want to do exactly this using sympy

Comment: Did you look here: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/plotting.html ?

Comment: What do the 2 arrays contain -- numbers or SymPy expressions? As mentioned in the link shared by @Georgy, SymPy internally uses Matplotlib.

Comment: @AmitSingh numbers